# Is there a simple way to find out which program triggers particular Windows notifications?

Tags: windows

I got a virus: now at least 30 Windows notifications a day show up, linking to spam websites. Windows Defender didn't find anything (wonderful). How can I find the location of the program triggering these notifications? I tried to right click on them but it does nothing.

Comment: My question is a lot more specific than "How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?". I might find useful information going through the answers to the linked question, but the linked question is definitely NOT the same question as mine. More importantly, people looking specifically for what I'm looking for will likely fail to find the linked question since these 2 questions are so different (although the overall subject is similar). I believe this post should not have been closed.

Comment: There is literally hundreds of hours of research in the linked question, covering every eventuality. If you can find something specific & unique to your question which merits keeping it as a separate QA, then please edit that into your existing question, which will promote it to the review queue for possible re-opening.

Comment: OK, but what's the point of this Stack Exchange site if, rather than providing very specific answers to very specific questions, instead provides one single bunch of answers covering a whole topic, within which users having all kinds of specific sub-questions are supposed to painstakingly look into? I thought Stack Exchange was meant to address things a lot more specifically than that. Have one giant thread per general topic then!

Comment: Questions that get asked many many times tend to be groupable into one large comprehensive answer. Each of those then marked as a duplicate is linked to the main, canonical, answer so can easily be traced. You have a virus, adware by the sounds of it - the canonical response to that is to completely erase your machine & restore from a known-good backup. The processes you allude to are probably ephemeral & will only spawn once each with a random name, making tracking each one a) impossible & b) pointless. You need to get to the root of the infection, not just try to kill each spawned process.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, that's bad new! I still believe my question deserves to get specific answers about finding the source of Windows notifications. More people will want to know that and not just because they've been infected by a virus.